# State equations partly time varying

Tags: control

I have A = [-1 0;0 -1] B = [1;1] and C = [t^2 1] To study observability, I can't use rank (C;CA) here due to time-variance. However, it seems, for controllability, we can still use rank (B AB). If this is because C has no impact on controllability, isn't there a conflict because the system is not strictly time-invariant?

Answer (score 1):

"Controllability" refers to being able to change states, to any arbitrary target, by means of the inputs. If A and B are time-invariant, then inputs-to-states relation is always the same. Therefore, the controllability matrix rank can tell you if the system is controllable.

To say that C changes with time is to say that the states-to-outputs relation changes. This means the system is not observable if \$t\$ is not known, but if \$t\$ is known, the system is possibly observable. One can evaluate \$C(t)\$, obtain an observability matrix, and check its rank.

The following matlab code shows that your system is neither controllable or observable for \$t\$ from 0 to 100.

```
A = [-1 0; 0 -1];
B = [1; 1];
rank(ctrb(A,B)) % rank = 1, system is not controlable

t = 0:100;
R = zeros(1,length(t));
for i = 1:length(t)
    C = [t(i)^2 1];
    R(i) = rank(obsv(A,C));
end
find(R == 2) % empty, system is not observable in evaluated time range
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I think there is a caveat though. Pointwise-in-time interpretations of observability can be misleading, right? Isn't the proper way is to evaluate the observability grammian and check its invertibility?

Comment: Pointwise is not misleading in this case because C(t) is a monotonic expression and A is constant, so one can heuristically evaluate ranges. If we had a more complicated expression for C(t), or if A(t) was time-varying, then point-wise is more misleading. The wikipedia entry for the observability grammian shows that the time-varying case is in essence a pointwise evaluation. Relevant to application, you could always say that without knowledge of t, or if you find just one t that makes the system not observable, then the entirety of the system is not observable.

Comment: I see what you're seeing. The definition of the observability grammian in wiki is slightly different from that in Wilson Rugh's book (which defines it on [t0,tf]) but thanks for pointing this out.